# Web.py / No module named 'utils'`

Tags: python

I'm trying to install [web.py](http://webpy.org/install), and I did the next steps:

- Download `web.py-0.3.7`, and extract it on `c://web.py-0.3.7`
- Run the next command:`C:\>python C:\web.py-0.37\setup.py install`
- and it gives me the next error: `import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror ImportError: No module named 'utils'`

How can I install and use `web.py`?

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: @Drewness: Python version 3.4.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is web.py is native for python 2.7+, however, there are several options.

- Install python 2.7+ (recommend using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv))
- Check out [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webpy/NvDqKEEEMEI) group that is porting web.py to python 3.x
- Use [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) as an alternative (Native to 2.5+ **and** 3.x)

Aside from these options to directly address the issue of 'utils' not being found, you can download the package [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-utils/). This *does not* get around the compatibility issues but just for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!   As of 2016 web.py for Python3 is a dead project, with the last mail list message in 2014 lamenting the lack of activity over the previous year.  Bottle in contrast has both current activity and lots of mindshare (2 pages of bottle-xyz pypi projects).   The choice is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same Error using `pip install`. I just ran `pip2 install web.py` and it successfully installed. (for anyone still reading this in 2016)

Comment: This implies you have multiple versions of Python installed globally. It is much better to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) when you need to install packages to a specific project.

Answer (score 0):

`web/__init__.py` relies on relative path. Try this:

> pip install web.py==0.40.dev0

A website had this solution