# Python: Alternative for web.py on python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py

I tried installing web.py module via pip, but I got an import error. Specifically

```
import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

So I realized that it had something to do with the fact that web.py is not compatible with python3.x. So the question is, what alternatives do I have? Would I be better of installing python 2.7+ alongside python3? Or is there a way I could use this module online with a python 2.7+ interpreter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web.py / No module named 'utils'\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663983/web-py-no-module-named-utils)

Comment: I'm reading a book where I must use web.py to follow the exercises. Installing python 2.7 is sort of a last option for me so I want to see other alternatives. As for the bottle.py option, I'll check it out @MichaelKohl

Comment: Are you on Linux? If so, you could easily switch between python3 and python2.7 using update-alternatives.

Comment: None of these are top-level modules; they're part of the ``web`` namespace.  So you'd need use either ``import web.utils``, or ``from web import utils``.

Comment: The link in the first comment is very interesting. Try bottle.py, it seems to work well and web.py seems to be dead for python3.

Comment: The thing is that I don't think I'll know how to use it and I don't think the functions would be the same as web.py

Comment: It still says no module named utils and I can literally open the utils.py module. my web module is located in Lib/site-packages is that alright? Note that I'm using python 3 btw @jasonharper

Answer (score 9):

Right. The problem is `web.py` is not yet compatible with python3. A new version is on it's way, but you need to consider your current requirements. Python2 can easily live with python3, so that's a very viable option. So, if you're looking for near-term use & you don't want to learn something else (like `bottle.py`) feel free to use web.py and python27.

If you're experimenting and want to try `web.py` with python3, Anand has reported that python3 is almost ready. Install with:

```
pip install web.py==0.40.dev0
```